# run sql in parallel using future: but the sql is not executed

Tags: clojure, future

I have the following function

```
(defn run [x]          
  (doseq [i  (range 1 x)]
     (println i)
     (future (j/execute! vertica-db ["insert /*+ direct */ into a select * from a limit 1"]))
   ))
```

when call it using

```
(run 100)
```

it will print 1..99, however if check the row number of table a, the row number is not increased which mean the sql is not executed. How to run the sql in parallel?

Comment: Have you checked that your sql code is working without the future?

Comment: yes it work. Also if I just use dotimes instead of doseq, it also work. Maybe doseq is lazy?

Comment: @DanielWu `doseq` is eager. If it wasn't, it's use with side-effects would become much more difficult (i.e. one would have to force it for side-effects to happen).

Comment: When I take your code and replace the SQL execution code with a simple println statement, it gets executed. Whatever is wrong, I seriously doubt it's related to the use of `doseq` and `future`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only suspicious thing I see in your code is the fact that you never wait for the futures to finish (so maybe they don't ?).

You need to collect the values returned by `future` calls and then block until they finish by using `(deref f)`/`@f` (i.e. dereferencing the future) where `f` is one of those values.

Something like this should work:

```
(defn run [x]
  (let [db-insert (fn [i] ((println i) (future (j/execute! vertica-db ["insert /*+ direct */ into a select * from a limit 1"]))))
        inserts (doall (map db-insert (range 1 x)))] ;force execution of all the db-insert calls
        (doseq [insert inserts] @insert))) ;wait for all the futures to finish
```

Comment: I don't need the wait since I am testing multiple insert. dotimes works while doseq doesn't. Not sure why they are different

Comment: @DanielWu What I was trying to say is that if you wait for the futures to finish you can be certain that the statements got executed (or failed). Without that you might have been unlucky enough to be checking the db before all the futures return. Long shot, but worth a try, since I don't see any other problems with your code.